# End user reports slurm jobs suddenly died with little in logs to find out why

Tags: slurm

I got a bunch of messages in slurm with the following:

```
[2023-11-16T10:03:53.952] _slurm_rpc_kill_job: REQUEST_KILL_JOB JobId=50461580 uid 1900007651
[2023-11-16T10:03:53.958] _slurm_rpc_kill_job: REQUEST_KILL_JOB JobId=50521673_[2-183] uid 1900007651                                                                                       
[2023-11-16T10:03:53.958] _slurm_rpc_kill_job: REQUEST_KILL_JOB JobId=50523246_[1-198] uid 1900007651                                                                                       
[2023-11-16T10:03:53.958] _slurm_rpc_kill_job: REQUEST_KILL_JOB JobId=50522320_[278-377] uid 1900007651                                                                                     
[2023-11-16T10:03:53.958] _slurm_rpc_kill_job: REQUEST_KILL_JOB JobId=50522600_[1-377] uid 1900007651                                                                                       
[2023-11-16T10:03:53.958] _slurm_rpc_kill_job: REQUEST_KILL_JOB JobId=50527650_[13-71] uid 1900007651                                                                                       
[2023-11-16T10:03:53.958] _slurm_rpc_kill_job: REQUEST_KILL_JOB JobId=50521231_[1-377] uid 1900007651                                                                                       
[2023-11-16T10:03:53.958] _slurm_rpc_kill_job: REQUEST_KILL_JOB JobId=50463285_45214 uid 1900007651                                                                                         
[2023-11-16T10:03:53.958] _slurm_rpc_kill_job: REQUEST_KILL_JOB JobId=50523630_[1] uid 1900007651                                                                                           
[2023-11-16T10:03:53.958] _slurm_rpc_kill_job: REQUEST_KILL_JOB JobId=50519949_[156-377] uid 1900007651                                                                                     
[2023-11-16T10:03:53.962] _slurm_rpc_kill_job: REQUEST_KILL_JOB JobId=50463285_45215 uid 1900007651                                                                                         
[2023-11-16T10:03:53.962] _slurm_rpc_kill_job: REQUEST_KILL_JOB JobId=50463285_45216 uid 1900007651                                                                                         
[2023-11-16T10:03:53.963] _slurm_rpc_kill_job: REQUEST_KILL_JOB JobId=50463285_45217 uid 1900007651                                                                                         
[2023-11-16T10:03:53.963] _slurm_rpc_kill_job: REQUEST_KILL_JOB JobId=50463285_45219 uid 1900007651                                                                                         
[2023-11-16T10:03:53.963] _slurm_rpc_kill_job: REQUEST_KILL_JOB JobId=50463285_45220 uid 1900007651
```

with the end user claiming that the jobs were killed after they were in hold for two days. I couldn't find much information otherwise on why they were killed. The only other thing I could find in the logs around this time was some stuff about accrue time, but that's not part of the QoS and from what I can find, that can be ignored if not using it as part of the QoS.

```
[2023-11-16T10:03:53.963] error: _remove_accrue_time_internal: QOS memlim acct qsg accrue_cnt underflow                                                                                     
[2023-11-16T10:03:53.963] error: _remove_accrue_time_internal: QOS memlim user 1900008578 accrue_cnt underflow
```

Any ideas for why the job seemed to suddenly die?